# Subreport query criteria from Tag property still asks for Parameter

Tags: report, ms-access-2010, criteria, subreport

I have a query which is used in a report limited to the Tag property value.  This works when I run the report (rptSub) by itself but when I put this report (rptSub) inside another report (rptMain) and open the report (rptMain) I get the "Enter Parameter Value?" dialog asking for the "Reports!rptSub.Tag" value.  What am I doing wrong?  Is this even possible?

```
SELECT Hangar.HangarNumber, Hangar.Slot, Hangar.TenantName
FROM Hangar WHERE (((Hangar.Slot)=[Reports]![rptSub].[Tag]));
```

ASIDE: Ultimately I want to put many of the same subreports (rptSub) on the main report (rptMain) with different Tag property values on each subreport control field in the main report (rptMain.)

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: Subforms and subreports are referred to in a different way http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm. I would be a little cautious about tag, it is a text property and not so easy to control.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to accomplish this using Link Master/Child Fields instead of the Tags.